# ASP.NET Google Reporting API values differ from Google Analytics Dashboard

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

**Report**

I have read this thread: [Google Analytics API: Why is the API data different than what's being seen on the Analytics Dashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38791878/google-analytics-api-why-is-the-api-data-different-than-whats-being-seen-on-th) But still cannot figure out why my results differ so much from my Analytics Dashboard.

[image]

How can I check in .Net if my response contains sampleData? Here is the code I am using:

```
string[] s = new string[]{"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"};

var auth = GoogleAnalyticsServiceAccount.AuthenticateServiceAccount("XXXXX", "D:\\Spawtz\\Src\\client_id.json", s);

// Create the DateRange object.

//DateRange lastWeek = new DateRange() { StartDate = "2018-12-02", EndDate = "2018-12-09" };

DateRange lastMonth = new DateRange() { StartDate = "2018-11-09", EndDate = "2018-12-09" };

DateRange lastYear = new DateRange() { StartDate = "2017-12-09", EndDate = "2018-12-09" };

// Create the Metrics object.

Metric pageViews = new Metric { Expression = "ga:pageViews"};

//Create the Dimensions object.

Dimension pagePath = new Dimension { Name = "ga:pagePath" };

// Create the ReportRequest object.
// Create the ReportRequest object.

ReportRequest reportRequest = new ReportRequest

        {
            ViewId = "XXXXX",
            DateRanges = new List<DateRange>() { lastMonth, lastYear},
            Dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { pagePath },
            Metrics = new List<Metric>() { pageViews },
            FiltersExpression = "ga:pagePath==/cricket-player/t20/playerid=2348"

        };

List<ReportRequest> requests = new List<ReportRequest>();            
requests.Add(reportRequest);

// Create the GetReportsRequest object.

GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest() { ReportRequests = requests };

// Call the batchGet method.

GetReportsResponse response = auth.Reports.BatchGet(getReport).Execute();
```

Can I set the SamplingLevel and Max-Results in asp.Net?

Comment: Please take a picture of the numbers you are seeing in the dashbaord and then the results you are seeing from running your code.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. Here is the two images taken for same dateRange Value: https://ibb.co/QpQCBRw
https://ibb.co/JRKf7sZ

Comment: @DeonLastManStands - in your code you have `/cricket-player/t20/playerid=2348` but in the screenshot it has `/cricket-player/t20&playerid=2348` - could be skewing things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can set up the [Sampling level](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#sampling) for your report.  It should be something like this Let me know if it doesnt work i can test it.

```
ReportRequest reportRequest = new ReportRequest
    {
        ViewId = "XXXXX",
        DateRanges = new List<DateRange>() { lastMonth, lastYear},
        Dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { pagePath },
        Metrics = new List<Metric>() { pageViews },
```

**isDataGolden**

The response data for each report should return a value called isDataGolden if the data is completed processing.

**TIP**

Remember that your request in the dashboard must be exactly the same as the request you are making to the API if you want the data to be the same.   The exact same dimensions, metrics and dates.  You cant look at a report in the dashbaord that contains five dimensions and then make a request to the api only looking at pageviews the numbers will not add up.

```
        FiltersExpression = "ga:pagePath==/cricket-player/t20/playerid=2348"
        Sampling = "SAMPLINGUNSPECIFIED"
    };
```

**Update**

According to the picture you posted you are looking at a report with the following dimensions and metrics.

- page
- pageviews
- uniquepageviews
- avg time on page
- Entrances
- bournce rate
- % Exit
- page value

Your request to the api must make the exact same request which means you need to use the exact same dimensions and metrics.

Comment: Getting an error reportRequest does not contain definition for Sampling. It looks like it needs a type SamplingLevel ?

Comment: it looks like it is wanting a string value so I tried this: SamplingLevel = "SAMPLINGUNSPECIFIED" - but still not working.

Comment: Check update your not using the same dimensions and metrics in the request as you are looking at in your report.

Comment: ok, so even if I am ONLY looking for the pageviews over that time do I need to put in those values? Is there a better way than above to only look for the total pageviews for a dateRange?

Comment: Sampling = "SAMPLINGUNSPECIFIED"  also not working, same error as above.

Comment: It doesnt matter if you are only looking for page views. If you want the results to match then you must create the same report. Sampling will not change that.   You cant compare cars and apples they are different.  Create the same report and you will get the same numbers back.  This is a multi dimensional database not a relational database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! The only thing I don't understand is that in the pic I sent the dimensions and metrics you mentioned are part of the result when I change the date on the Dashboard. What is the meaning of the results that I got in my query then? Are they sampled or are they correct pageviews count for any possible metric and dimensions or just sampled data? is Including all above mentioned metrics and dimensions the best way to get amount of pageviews for a URL?

Comment: This has nothing to do with sampled data unless you have a website with a few million hits a data.   The results are the results for the exact query that you make.  Analysis works based upon the dimensions, metrics you request over a date period for a view.    If you want to compare things they need to be exactly the same or the analysis is not going to match. https://searchoracle.techtarget.com/definition/multidimensional-database